# Как ускорить чтение данных из InputStream в java.net Socket?

Tags: java, сокет

Есть java.net Socket

```
    private Socket clientSocket;
    private BufferedReader is;
    private Writer out;

    public ClientServiceThread(Socket clientSocket) throws IOException {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        clientSocket.setTcpNoDelay(true);

        this.is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        this.out = new OutputStreamWriter(this.clientSocket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");

        String str = convert(is);
    }
```

Через сокет принимается относительно большой объем данных Base64.

Чтение данных занимает длительное время.

```
public String convert(BufferedReader reader) throws IOException {

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);

        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
```

Как правильно и эффективно читать данные, а именно, чтобы это происходило быстрее?

Comment: вопрос, а зачем base64?

Comment: видимо так решили, когда разрабатывали этот код ранее.

Comment: это некисло добавляет длину, при том что в случае с сокетами это не нужно

Comment: отправляющую сторону нет возможности изменять.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решился переходом на com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer.
В java.net Socket чтение выпоняется медленно.